# Woocommerce product qty shortcode not working on mobile browsers

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I've got an with a site, we've got this shortcode on it:

```
if( !function_exists('show_specific_product_quantity') ) {

function show_specific_product_quantity( $atts ) {

    // Shortcode Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id' => '', // Product ID argument
        ),
        $atts,
        'product_qty'
    );

    if( empty($atts['id'])) return;

    $stock_quantity = 0;

    $product_obj = wc_get_product( intval( $atts['id'] ) );
    $stock_quantity = $product_obj->get_stock_quantity();

    if( $stock_quantity > 0 ) {
        return $stock_quantity;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

add_shortcode( 'product_qty', 'show_specific_product_quantity' );}
```

Which shows the current stock level of the product ID and it works perfectly on desktop browsers but mobile browsers it only shows the max stock level all the time.

It's simply used like this:

```
[product_qty id='2329']
```

And every desktop browser, including the emulated mobile viewports in Chrome and Elementors responsive mode show it correctly.  Even on Chrome mobile, if you set it to desktop mode, the correct stock level is shown. It's only on native mobile browsers that it doesn't seem to work.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Other prevailing editing advice is: (a) technical writing is preferred; (b) Stack Overflow is not a chatroom, since posts are written for the benefit of a wide future audience; (c) titles are generally preferred in sentence case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a weird caching problem that was being caused by Siteground's Optimisation plugin.  I haven't figured out which if the three caching options is the cause yet, but I'll update this answer when I do.

It was also preventing custom add to cart links from working, again only in mobile.  So a weird problem and one I'll be reporting to Siteground.